# How to link Module with a Button in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I open-up VBA and then create a module where I put the code into. I then co create a Comman button (Activex Control) and then link it to the module.

However, I’m doing something wrong because I’m getting an error “subscript out of range”

[image: Code in Module]

[image: Button linking to module]

Can anyone give me some advice regarding linking modules with button in VBA

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)

  Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
  Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
  Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
  Dim row As Long, col As Integer

  Set report = Workbooks.Add

  With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws1col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  maxrow = ws1row
  maxcol = ws1col
  If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
  If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

  difference = 0

  For col = 1 To maxcol
    For row = 1 To maxrow
      colval1 = ""
      colval2 = ""
      colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
      colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula
      If colval1 <> colval2 Then
        difference = difference + 1
        Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<> " & colval2
        Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
        Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
      End If
    Next row
  Next col

  Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
  report.Saved = True

  If difference = 0 Then
    report.Close False
  End If
  Set report = Nothing
  MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, _
         "Comparing Two       Worksheets"
End Sub
```

Comment: At what line in the code does this occur? What is your code? Are you making the correct references to the worksheets?

Comment: I don't know if I'm linking it right . The error is coming in the button link Compare2WorkSheets Worksheets(“Sheet1”), Worksheets(“Sheet2”)

Comment: And add the actual text of the code to your question so that we can easily copy/paste it

Comment: Instead of pictures

Comment: Now it is fixed bc once I was uploading I could normally upload the pictures. it would only show the link

Comment: If all the picture is good for is the text in the picture, then Stack Overflow prefers text rather than the picture.

Comment: Can you give me any advice on why I'm getting an error

Comment: A problem I can see from your picture implies that your code line `Compare2WorkSheets Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2")` ***looks*** like you typed it in a different editor and pasted the code into your VBA editor. I'm saying this because the double-quotes look like smart-quotes (`“` and `”`) to me, instead of using the normal double-quote (`"`).

Comment: @PeterT thank you a lot. it seems like the problem was  on quotes.